# Math Lessons with Two Parts and a Combination

Tags: terminology, education

This is fairly open ended, so I understand if people consider this to be off-topic.

I'm interested in creating math lessons where two groups each learn how to use a different simple math skill, and then the groups are combined and challenged with problem types that require both skills.

Here's a simple example:

**Group A** would learn the definition of factorial and run some easy factorial problems.

**Group B** would learn that if you have certain fractions (like $\frac{8 \cdot 15}{5}$) it's easier to cancel first and then multiply.

**Combined Groups** form with a mix of people from both groups A and B.  They are given problems like evaluating $\frac{10!}{8!}$ where having both skills makes running the problem pretty easy.

Is there a specific name for this sort of collaborative learning? What are some fun/interesting problems to run in this way?

Comment: This may (also) be interesting to those on [the math education stack](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into that.

Comment: Posted to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/math-lessons-with-two-parts-and-a-combination